# Unable to get latitude and longitude user - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, latitude-longitude, geolocator

I am using google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.0 and geolocator: ^9.0.1 and trying to get user latitude and longitude by running this code from geolocator package:

```
Position posisiNow = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

The problem is... I always getting error when trying to reach `posisiNow.latitude` or `posisiNow.longitude` but when I only print `posisiNow` I get good result:`Latitude: 37.33233141, Longitude: -122.0312186`. The error when I try to print `posisiNow.latitude` is: `NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'latitude' was called on null.`
I need that data because I need to put latitude and longitude in this function of google_maps_flutter:

```
controllerNow.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
              CameraPosition(
                  bearing: 192.8334901395799,
                  target: LatLng(posisiNow.latitude, posisiNow.longitude),
                  tilt: 0,
                  zoom: 16.00)));
```

This problem only in ios Simulator, I have tried in android and worked fine. I also open this question in https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/1135

Comment: On IOS simulator you need to enable the simulation of location updates using the "Debug" -> "Location" options from the menu.

Comment: You can find more details on https://www.willowtreeapps.com/craft/simulating-location-in-ios

Comment: Hi I try the information from the link you given and my configuration seems alright and when I check Features - Location.. it is enable @ctrl_aziz

Answer (score 0):

Here `target: LatLng(posisiNow.latitude, posisiNow.longitude),` the latitude and longitude cannot be null. You can either provide default fallback values .
target: LatLng(posisiNow.latitude ?? 0.0, posisiNow.longitude ?? 0.0), you need to make `Position?` nullable.

Also you can get location before building this widget. eg in init state.

Comment: Hi, I try to change the target into your code:``` LatLng(posisiNow.latitude ?? 0.0, posisiNow.longitude ?? 0.0),``` but I think I can not change ```Position``` into ```Position?``` because the default is non-nullable